# C - double free

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

struct strqueue {
    struct lnode *front;
    struct lnode *back;
    int length;
};

struct lnode {
    char *item;
    struct lnode *next;
};

StrQueue create_StrQueue(void) {
    struct strqueue *sq = malloc(sizeof(struct strqueue));
    sq->length = 0;
    sq->front = NULL;
    sq->back = NULL;
    return sq;
}

void destroy_nodes(struct lnode *l) {
    while (l!=NULL) {
        struct lnode *c = l;
        l=l->next;
        free(c);
    }
}

void destroy_StrQueue(StrQueue sq) {
    destroy_nodes(sq->front);
    free(sq);
}

void sq_add_back(StrQueue sq, const char *str) {
    struct lnode *n = malloc(sizeof(struct lnode));
    n->item = malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(str)+1));
    strcpy(n->item, str);
    n->next = NULL;
    if (sq->length == 0) {
        sq->front = n;
        sq->back = n;
    } else {
        sq->back->next = n;
        sq->back = n;
    }
    sq->length++;
}

char *sq_remove_front(StrQueue sq) {
   if (sq->front == NULL) {
      return NULL;
   } else {
      struct lnode *f = sq->front;
      char *temp = sq->front->item;
      sq->front = sq->front->next;
      sq->length--;
      //Delete the line below will not cause an error of not free all memory
      free(f->item);
      free(f);
      return temp;
   }
}

int sq_length(StrQueue sq) {
    return sq->length;
}
```

Here I wanna make the strqueue like a linked list but when I use it, it always says that I am attempting to double free something. Which part of my code is wrong? Is there a memory leak or something wrong about the memory allocation?

Comment: Random points: `sizeof(char)==1` always; no point in multiplying by it. Also, `malloc` + `strcpy` => `strdup`.

Comment: Can you show us an example test case that triggers the double free?

Comment: after each call to free() the code should set the related pointer to NULL, so a (accidental) further call to free on the pointer will have no effect.  free() properly handles a pointer that contains NULL.

Answer (score 4):

In

```
struct lnode *f = sq->front;
char *temp = sq->front->item;
sq->front = sq->front->next;
sq->length--;
//Delete the line below will not cause an error of not free all memory
free(f->item);
free(f);
return temp;
```

It returns pointer `temp` to `free`d memory in `free(f->item)`, reading the string through that pointer is undefined behaviour. And if you `free` it that is going to be the double `free`. Basically, the returned pointer is useless.

The fix would be to avoid doing `free(f->item)` in that function. The caller would need to free the pointer to the string after use.

---

Singly-linked list is best represented by:

```
struct lnode *head, **tail;
```

Initialized as:

```
head = NULL;
tail = &head;
```

In this case there is no need for special handling of an empty list on appending. Appending always is:

```
*tail = n;
tail = &n->next;
```

Removing from the front is:

```
struct lnode *n = head;
if(head) {
    head = head->next;
    if(!head) 
        tail = &head;
} 
return n;
```

Comment: Here is another question, now for remove_front, how can I return a char * without memory leak? If I have a pointer points to the original item and then I free the item, it will return nothing, but when I create a new char *, after returning it will not be freed so will this cause a memory leak?

Comment: Updated an answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this in `char *sq_remove_front(StrQueue sq)` :

```
if (f->item != NULL) {
    free(f->item);
    f->item = NULL;
}
if (f != NULL) {
    free(f);
    sq->front = NULL;
}
```

It would avoid performing `free()` twice on the pointers.